# I commit three times. How can I delete the second commit only?

Tags: git, github, commit

For example .

1. The first commit, the file code is:

   ```
   first commit.
   ```
2. The second commit, the file code is:

   ```
   first commit.
   second commit.
   ```
3. The third commit, the file code is:

   ```
   first commit.
   second commit.
   third commit.
   ```

How can I do use git to delete the second commit only?
    The file code is showing:

```
first commit.
third commit.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interactive rebase can make this easier:

```
git rebase -i HEAD^^
```

An editor will open showing the last two commits. You should delete the line with the commit you don't want (the top line), save the file, and quit the editor.

Git will then try to apply the third commit without the second one. Like as not this will fail. If so, you need to edit the files so they look like how you want, then complete the rebase process like this:

```
git add .
git rebase --continue
```

If you get in a horrible muddle ....

```
git rebase --abort
```